# is it possible to specify an index.html location for a passener + nginx app?

Tags: nginx, passenger

I have an nginx site config like:

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /home/app/public;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.7;
  passenger_app_root /home/app;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_user app;
  passenger_max_request_queue_size 3360;
  passenger_max_requests 3360;
  ...
}
```

`home/app`'s directory structure something like is:

```
(rails app)
app/
  controllers/
  ..etc
config/
  ..etc
public
  favicon.ico
  404.html
  frontend/
    index.html
    12345.js
    45678.js
    some-picture.jpg
```

I am trying to make it so that:

1. visiting `mydomain.com` will render the index file in `public/frontend`
2. any asset request will be served from `public` and then if it's not found, fallback to `public/frontend`.. For example: a request to `mydomain.com/favicon.ico` will serve the favicon in `public`, and a request to `mydomain.com/some-picture.jpg` will serve the jpeg in `public/frontend`.

...

When experimenting with a vanilla nginx config, I found that I could accomplish this by doing:

```
server {
  server_name mydomain.com;
  root /home/app/public;

  location = / {
    index /frontend/index.html;
  }

  location {
    try_files $uri /frontend/$uri;
  }
  ...
}
```

However it seems that once passenger is added to this mix, this no longer works...